# How to get application open and close time for all installed application

Tags: android

How can I get open and close time for all installed app. I have to create a app that will calculate app usages statics on phone.

Thanks,
Ajay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the application level you would need to run a service that periodically checks and tracks statistics itself. At the platform level, you should be able to easily make modifications to track this fairly accurately..

Comment: Thanks Mike, I am new to this android world. Can you please share some sample code or links with me.

Comment: Mike, I am waiting for your response.

Answer (score 1):

I donot think it is at all possible.